# Resources to create your own html 5 / css3 layout engine in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, web-standards, mshtml, layout-engine

Are there any resources out there for how to create your own layout engine (like webkit) in C#, that supports html 5 and css 3, preferably through MSHTML, or anything else.

Also, if the above is impossible, how can I add on to the webbrowsercontrol in WinForms .NET to help it support the latest web standards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change MSHTML, but you can use a different control instead of the default IE based one. Webkit, you can try  https://github.com/webkitdotnet (Still looks somewhat experimental though), and GeckoFX http://www.geckofx.org/ which aims to be a drop-in replacement using Gecko (Firefox layout engine).

I'm not sure if they both support all the features the normal WebBrowserControl does though.

Comment: Mono also seems to contain a WebBrowser replacement that uses either Gecko or WebKit, and could be better-maintained than `webkitdotnet`